# Ionic routing breaks when navigating to url twice

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When navigating through a page stack i've discovered that when i visit the same page twice the `<ion-back-button>` does not behave as expected. Here is a graphic of the issue.

[image]

It seems that Ionic does not navigate back from the last data of `Page 1` but rather of the first occurrence (red arrow). I've found a similar Github [issue 16516](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/16516) which should be fixed but it doesn't work for me.

Has anyone encountered this or can provide a fix/workaround?

**My Versions**

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
```

### update:

i created a [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/23119) on Github like suggested in the comments.

Comment: Is there a question here? This looks more like a bug report, which should go on the Ionic Github issues page.

Comment: The thing that bugs me is that it should be fixed. Also maybe someone has a fix for this and i'm simply doing smth wrong. But maybe you're right, i'll write a bug report if nothing comes up here

Comment: Well, I do get that, but in the end, this is just a question / answer medium and without any clear question in a post the post shouldn't be here. I wouldn't remark on it if you had asked a specific question, such as if others have the same problem and if there are any known work arounds, but since you're just stating something without asking anything it doesn't really fit into StackOverflow. Call me picky, but it makes it easier to keep things organized! :)

Comment: updated to provide a proper question. I simply forgot to specifically ask for it. I agree, there should be a question.

Comment: have you defined `defaulthref` on your `ion-back-button`?

Comment: this issue occurred if i set a `defaulthref` and if i don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across the exact same issue. I think the issue is based on the page url and not on the page component itself. If you navigate to an url that already exists in the navigation stack history, Ionic will redirect you to that existing page and will also remove all pages in between.

The workaround I'm using for now is to add a timestamp to each page's url that is likely to be added several times in the navigation stack. This will make sure that a new instance of a page component will be created and pushed into the stack instead of reusing an old one.

**Component**

```ts
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';

export class MyPage {

  constructor(private navController: NavController) {}

  navigate() {
    // You can use an NavigationOptions object if needed
    const options = { queryParams: { parameter: "value" } };
    this.navController.navigateForward(['/url', new Date().getTime()], options);
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<button (click)="navigate()">Navigate</button>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: `If you navigate to an url that already exists in the navigation stack history, Ionic will redirect you to that existing page and will also remove all pages in between`  This is exactly what my impression was

Comment: I'll research more and keep you posted on my findings.